# SVG elements from Figma don't align correctly when moving them to VSC

Tags: html, css, svg, figma

I recently started using Figma to design webpages. After I finished designing a page, I exported all the SVG files and added them to my HTML document. I went to copy the CSS styling from Figma, but everything was out of size resulting in everything being out of place.

I tried redesigning it with a bigger height/width but the same issue occurred.

Do I create the Figma canvas the size of my monitor resolution?

codepen: https://codepen.io/HasanTheSyrian_/pen/BaKLrrO 
Figma Library: https://www.figma.com/file/DXbkUoTm9W1uCJpwipeVCQ/MyFormWebsite?node-id=16%3A0

(the upper panel is the redesign attempted at trying to make the SVG elements the size of the browser the lower panels are the first panels that I thought fit)

Couldn't post the rest code here because it exceeded the limit of 3000 characters thanks to one of the SVG's 1000+ character count.

---

index.css

```
body {
   
    font-family: 'Alata', sans-serif;
    background-color: #E5E5E5;

}

header {

    display: flex;

    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 63px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    
    background: #009ABC;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 22px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);

}

.logo {
    
    width: 347px;
    height: 195px;
    left: -136px;
    top: -66px;
    position: absolute;

}

.upperTextContainer {

    position: absolute;
    width: 563px;
    height: 86px;
    left: 74px;
    top: 261px;    
    font-size: 62px;
    
    
    outline: none;
}

.lowerTextContainer {

    position: absolute;
    width: 780px;
    height: 82px;
    left: 74px;
    top: 359px;
    margin: 24px 0px 24px 0px;
    
    font-family: Alata;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 41px;
    
    color: #000000;
   
}

.coderIllustration {

    position: absolute;
    width: 594px;
    height: 451px;
    left: 170px;
    top: 509px;


}

.wave1 {
 
    position: absolute;
    width: 2191px;
    height: 854px;
    left: -34px;
    top: 106px;
    
    

} 

.wave2 {

    position: absolute;
    width: 2191px;
    height: 854px;
    left: -34px;
    top: 167px;
    
    

} 

.wave3 {

    position: absolute;
    width: 2191px;
    height: 854px;
    left: -34px;
    top: 247px;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to the svg